# OAuth 2.0, How to let the initiator know whether permission was granted/rejected?

Tags: oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk, shopify-app

I'm facing an issue with OAuth 2.0 (specifically for Shopify public apps).

When I initialize the OAuth flow from a website, I already have some *extra information*. When the user accepts the OAuth permission, it redirects to the `redirect_uri` with the authorization code. I can then request a long-lived access token from there.

But, inside the handler for the `redirect_uri`, I don't know what *extra information* are available during the initialization of the OAuth flow.

How can I let the initiator know if the OAuth request is granted/rejected?

N.B: Facebook provides a Login Button SDK which has an `onlogin` attribute. It allows specifying a callback when the permission request was granted/denied. I am looking for something similar

Answer (score 0):

Information available is much related to the OAuth scopes that you request. The smallest scope gives you the public profile that you can query with the access token that you have recieved. Make a request to

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email with the access_token in the authorization header. Work through the JSON response and you can figure this out.